# how to execute some function in every time page reload in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to execute function every time page reloads.

I used this, But its not working properly.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $rootScope.pageClass = "page-fadein-down";
});
```

How to do this angularjs or jquery?
Any help ?

Comment: on reload i am keeping some animation and remaining time i need to keep different type animation on state changes

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular `app.run()` block. [Angualr JS Module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.pageClass = "page-fadein-down";
}]);
```